# Collapse rows of a dataframe with common values and fill in blanks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a single data frame and every row is duplicated except for two values. In all cases the corresponding duplicate has a blank value in the corresponding row. I want to 'collapse' these rows and fill in the blanks.

In the example below, I want to collapse the top DataFrame to mirror the bottom

[image: Example Table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` + `first`; `first` skips over NaN values by default:

```
collapsed_df = df.groupby("feature_id").first().reset_index()
```

If the empty spaces are not NaN values, probably will want to fill them with NaN first:

```
df = df.replace('', np.nan)
```